# How to publish the module on just one page?

Tags: module, prestashop

I made a few changes in the default template and unfortunately I noticed that the modules (block categories, home slider and featured products) are published on all the pages of the site, and I want them public only on the Home page. How can I remove them? The site is not online.

http://oi61.tinypic.com/5b42mt.jpg

Answer (score 1):

On your back office go on the modules -> positions page, find your module and edit him, you will be able to choose the pages where you want your module being displayed.